# React native firebase onLink function is not getting any callback when app is opened from a link

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, react-native-firebase

I have implemented firebase deep linking in my Application. When app is closed and i click on link i am getting an event that app is opened from url.

```
firebase.links().getInitialLink().then(url => {
this._resolveDeepLink(url)
})
```

The above snippet works fine. I am facing issue when app is already open an exists in background and when i click the link, this time my app comes to foreground but i don't get any event that i came here from a link click.
Below is the code snippet that that i am using

```
firebase.links().onLink((url) => {
console.warn(url)
})
```

**url** should have the deeplink url associated with it.

Comment: do you find any solution for this problem ?

Comment: Nooooooooooooo0

Comment: Same here. Still no answer?

Comment: DId you solve this issue?

Answer (score -4):

You need use

> firebase.links().onLink((url) => {
>         console.log(url);
>       });

For get URL when app is running